# Convert String to UTF-8 hex

Tags: android, kotlin, utf-8

What I am trying to do is to convert special characters to its converted utf-8 hex if it is not on ASCII reference.

So for example I have a string of:

```
{
 "message": "",
 "to_email": "someone@gmail.com"
}
```

It should be converted into

```
 {
 "message": "\xF0\x9F\x98\x80 ",
 "to_email": "someone@gmail.com"
}
```

I tried using escapeJava of Apache Common Language but it uses UTF-16 so the current output is

```
{
"message": "\uD83D\uDE00",
"to_email": "someone@gmail.com"
}
```

Comment: `non UTF-8 characters ` ? All characters can be represented by UTF-8. What do you mean?

Comment: @blackapps i mean convert any special characters to its utf-8 hex if it has no value on ASCII.

Comment: Note: last example if not UTF-16. (UTF-16 should not use surrogates). Using `\u` (or `\U`) is the best way: you keep most semantic of Unicode as possible, and compiler will transform to the right encoding. Note2: you added an extra space on your second example.

Comment: The last example **is** UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

In java you can use

```
byte[] bytes = "".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
for (byte b:bytes) {
    System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(b));
}
```

for kotlin

```
val hexString = java.lang.Integer.toHexString(i)
```